# Importing from few directories down python

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

This is my file structure.

```
- scraper_backend
     - jobs
         - bronze
             - extract_bronze.py
-tests
    - jobs
        - bronze
             - extract_bronze_test.py
```

Now when I try to import this `extract_bronze.py` file I get this error.

```
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\School\Academiejaar 3\Semester 2\internship2023-solarstreaming\tests\unit_tests\jobs\bronze\test_extract_bronze.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\unit_tests\jobs\bronze\test_extract_bronze.py:4: in <module>
    from .....scraper_backend.jobs.bronze import extract_bronze
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
===================================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================================== 
ERROR tests/unit_tests/jobs/bronze/test_extract_bronze.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
======================================================================================== 1 error in 0.13s =========================================================================================
```

I do the import like this.

```
from datetime import datetime
from .....scraper_backend.jobs.bronze import extract_bronze # <------ this import
# also tried 
# from scraper_backend.jobs.bronze import extract_bronze


def test_extract_energy_happy():
    energy_type = "solar"
    params = {
        "datetime": datetime.now(),
        "province": "Antwerp"
    }
    date_time = datetime.now()
    result = extract_bronze.extract_energy(energy_type, params, date_time)
    assert type(result) != str
    assert type(result) == float
```

Also when moving the file in the `tests` folder and not in other sub folders it runs fine. So the problem is with that it is maybe nested to deep.
I have tried apppending to path with sys but i'm looking for a nicer solution
All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what's causing this, but maybe you should have a look at making you project into a "proper" python package (e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-a-python-package/). You can then install it locally with `pip install -e .` from the root directory. This will let you do things like `from my_pkg.scraper_backend.jobs.bronze import extract_bronze`, which will make your tests simpler :)

Comment: has ``scraper_backend`` a ``__init__.py``? Otherwise it won't be recognized as a package.

Comment: Yes every folder has an `__init__.py` file